# aerospike: difference between recored inside set and without set

Tags: database-design, aerospike

Aerospike supports record within `set` and directly within `namespace` (without any `set`). What are the use cases for the later one? Is there any performance wise or functionality limitation on them ?

**My case:** I will have lots (1 Billion) of records in a set say `test_set` within a bin named `test_bin_value`. Now I want to keep track of latest record update/insert time in bin `update_timestamp`. This bin's value will be updated whenever someone insert or update record in bin `test_bin_value`. Should i keep bin `update_timestamp` inside set `test_set` or outside ? If i will keep it within same set, will it take more space ? There will be frequent read and write operation on both bins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if a record exists within a set, all of the bins would exist within that set.  You can think of a set as analogous to a table in a SQL database, the set name is contained within the header of the record and as such applies to all bins in that record.

If you are using a set name, the overhead is 9 + set_name_length bytes per record.

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/plan/capacity/